# Ionic3 - How do avoid scrolling on a single html item?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a simple full screen page that shows a photo and you can enter a caption. The trouble I am having is that when I focus on the input box, the page scrolls and half the image is removed.

```
<ion-content fullscreen [ngClass]="{'focus': focus, 'focus-out': !focus}" class="focus" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + image + ')'}" no-border>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar color="transparent">
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col col-10>
                    <image-caption (caption)="saveCaption($event)" (focusIn)="focus = true" (focusOut)="focus = false"></image-caption>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

I would like the ion-content not to scroll but the text box (inside image-caption component) to appear when focused. I have tried `no-scroll` and `no-bounce` in `ion-content`. I have also tried the native keyboard method to disable scroll `this.keyboard.disableScroll(true);`

Can I disable scroll on one item? The other solution I see here is to disable scroll and change to position of the input box to show when the keyboard is shown.

Comment: are you building for android ?

Comment: Could you please add a gif of the issue? Because there are several issues related to the keyboard, and there're also several ways to fix it...

Comment: This is on iOS, never tried it on android.

Comment: Cannot reply with a gif here but what I want is for the background image in ion-content not to scroll so it is fully displayed on the device but the ion-footer (which only contains an input box) to always show when the keyboard is shown on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using transform to scale the image but the problem seems to be solved.